# Need to convert the timestamps in milliseconds from epoch and calculate difference then present in a specific format

Tags: perl, datetime, time, perl-module, subroutine

I am relatively new to Perl, i have a query as detailed below.

Consider these are the timestamps retrieved from another program in milliseconds.
Time1 = 1404819151646
Time2 = 1404819485977

How to pass these times to a perl subroutine, and get the difference between them in below format:
seconds.milliseconds

Note: I am assuming that since the timestamps are in milliseconds and perl is calculating the difference between Time2 and Time1, it will take care of corner cases, like date change or month changes as well. Correct me if i am wrong.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

By calculating difference and dividing by 1000 to get seconds; milliseconds don't care about dates, months, etc.

```
sub diff {
  my ($aa, $bb) = @_

  return ($bb - $aa)/1000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what if the time was in "Jul 8 2014 17:59:55.455" format?

Comment: @NitinSagar `Jul 8 2014 17:59:55.455` is not a time-stamp and you'll need some module to convert it to milliseconds first.